# Kubernetes kube-dns TLS certificate validation

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I'm using kubernetes v1.5.2, and have implemented api over tls. Problem is that while deploying kube-dns I'm getting message on minion as:

```
Mar 23 10:06:27 node01 journal: I0323 09:06:27.007407       1 dns.go:172]   Ignoring error while waiting for service default/kubernetes: Get  https://10.254.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes: x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.254.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs. Sleeping 1s before retrying.
```

I've tried by using curl, from another pod and it fails without --insecure switch, whit it it is ok.

I understand that 10.254.0.1:443 actually serves certificate from master node (api on port 6443)(192.168.0.200), but how to resolve it, that 10.254.0.1 serves its valid certificate.

Here is description from clusterip api:
    [root@master01 dns]# kubectl describe service kubernetes
    Name:                   kubernetes
    Namespace:              default
    Labels:                 component=apiserver
                            provider=kubernetes
    Selector:               
    Type:                   ClusterIP
    IP:                     10.254.0.1
    Port:                   https   443/TCP
    Endpoints:              192.168.2.200:6443
    Session Affinity:       ClientIP

Thanks 
Dubravko

Comment: Are you using a custom SSL certificate? How did you generate it?

Comment: I'm using SAN certificates, how I have DNS:master01, DNS:master01.lab.cs, IP Address:192.160.2.200, IP Address:10.254.0.1

Comment: yes, I'm asking if you generated the certificate yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the service IP your API server certificate **must** have IP:10.254.0.1 as a SAN.

Likewise if you reach the API using the service name `kubernetes.default` the certificate must have this name as a SAN.

A good practice is to request a certificate with at least the following SAN:

- IP:(first IP of service CIDR)
- DNS:kubernetes
- DNS:kubernetes.default
- DNS:kubernetes.default.svc
- DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local

Check this util script for reference: [util.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/cc2250cb982091bf72822e168296f34dc038c271/cluster/photon-controller/util.sh#L428)